# Dynamic User Group Authorization in .NET Core

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization

I would like to know if anyone has any suggestions on how to dynamically create user groups, populate those groups with users and then use authorization logic to restrict access to views based on group ownership which is also decided at run time.   Sorry for the broadness of this question but while I do have quite a bit of experience with .NET in on the desktop I have very little experience in .NET Normal/Core MVC web frameworks.

Recap of Specs

**Authorization Tasks Required at Run Time**

- Create Groups
- Assign Users to Groups
- Restrict Access to Views to certain Groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to build more context about app needs. there can be many implications to `group` and `dynamic`.

In the world of auth, from my experiance, groups are meant for data security or even row level security. So more info needed here. but it is abstracted, each app can decide what the term really mean in the code.

If you want to restriect views, I would suggest using policies, they have runtime capabilies and you can store them in your database and do general use.

How to assign them? that is really depends on your app... there can be many many usecases.

1. your user join by himself, you need to save him to the database with the policy.
2. your user is created by some else in the app, you can attach him to policy or support  that in the UI.
3. use get more access after time passes... again, you have to decide of thats automatic or not...

here is example how to restreict manually:

```
public class ContentController : Controller
{
  private IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;
  public ContentController (IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
  {
    _authorizationService = authorizationService;
  }

  public async Task<IActionResult> Save(Article article)
  {    var allowed = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "ContentsEditor"));
    if (!allowed)
      throw new SomeAuthException();

    // ok, goot to go....
    ...
  }
}
```

you have more "infrastructured" ways to implement that, but this is just an example

Please read here for best practice about using policy: https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/creating-dynamic-authorization-policies-aspnet-core/

Comment: To be clear by group I just mean any collection of users and dynamic meaning that they can be added or removed at runtime.  Thanks for the assist I will give "policies" and look see.

Comment: @Brian if my answer helped you please accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you need is dynamic authorization aka attribute-based access control([abac](/questions/tagged/abac)). With ABAC, you define policies that use attributes of the user, action, and resource. There are plenty of systems that do that out there:

- [xacml](/questions/tagged/xacml) - you can find more information [here](https://www.axiomatics.com/attribute-based-access-control/).
- [alfa](/questions/tagged/alfa)
- Rego